# Use SSMS to Create Database Diagrams but not Database Objects

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to be able to create a database diagram without actually creating database objects.  It seems like the best way to do this would be directly through SSMS.  My only question is, is there a way to **not** have SSMS create the database objects when you create them in the database diagram?

I want this as a planning and design tool, not necessarily for implementation yet.  I just want to lay it all out without actually creating any tables yet.  When I am in the Database Diagram and click *New Table*, I just want it to create the new table to be used in the diagram as opposed to a table database object being created in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK - there is no way to do it in SSMS, use other tools for that, such as Microsoft Visio, ERWin etc. - there are a lot of them.

You may create a dummy database and draw you diagrams there, thinking of underlying creating objects as about a part of diagram itself. 8-)

Comment: Note that visio pro won't let you generate a database from the model.  The version that comes with VS2002 or VS2003 enterprise architect comes with a subsystem that does.  The type library for the DB modelling engine is also incomplete and it doesn't expose automation interfaces, so you can only get at it through in-process VBA code.